# Reconnecting to socket channel after disconnection in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, next.js, fastify

There's various answers to this question, but either they're outdated (I don't think the "reconnect" event exist anymore?) or just doesn't work for me.

I have a ton of data that the client is waiting for from the server via socket.io sockets. It's fine until 10-15 minutes later with over 1600 results that the socket reconnects. After the reconnection happens, I do not get anymore of the data that the server emits, which I assume is because I've lost the events from the original socket connection.

I have to refresh to continue getting that data.

How do I reconnect to socket.io after every reconnection?

**Client:**

socket.js (context)

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

export const SocketContext = createContext();
```

Layout.js

```
import { socket, SocketContext } from '../context/socket'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  </SocketContext.Provider>
}
```

page (next.js)

```
  import { SocketContext } from '../context/socket'; 
  ...
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('joined', socketChannel);
    socket.on(socketChannel, handleStream);
  }, []);
```

**Server:**

index.js (Uses [fastify-socket.io](https://github.com/alemagio/fastify-socket.io))

```
    fastify.io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.on('joined', (channel) => {
            socket.join(channel);
        })
    });
    redis.subscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => {
        io.to(channel).emit(channel, message);
    });
```

Comment: Reconnecting is automatic by default. Is there a reason you using `forceNew: true`? Seems like you are managing the connecting in React Context, can you share that code.

Comment: I was trying to manage the connection from another answer but that did not work, i'll update and fix the code.

Comment: Can you share the `createContext()` code, I assume this uses `React.Context`?

Comment: @SamuelGoldenbaum I did already, I guess I did not make it clear enough, updated the question.

Comment: ok, think I spot the issue

Comment: socket.io by default reconnects when it get disconnected. But remember the socket id will be different on each connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.io will automatically leave the rooms when you have a disconnect.

> Rooms are left automatically upon disconnection.

in `useEffect()`, you are joining the room once:

```
  socket.emit('joined', socketChannel);
  socket.on(socketChannel, handleStream);
```

Two options:

1. Automatically join at connect on client:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on(socketChannel, handleStream);

    // connect fires when connected, also after reconnected
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connect', socket.connected);
      // automatically join the room
      socket.emit('joined', socketChannel);
    });
  }, []);
```

2. Automatically join at the server, but this assumes all clients join the relevant room which may not be suitable:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`${socket.id} connected`);

  // automatically join the room
  socket.join(socketChannel);
  ...
```

Comment: Hello, I try to emit a disconnect event when I leave the room but it does not get fired
`useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      socket.emit("join-room", {
        username: context.user.first_name + Math.random(),
        roomname: id,
      });
    });

    return () => socket.on("discon");
  }, []);`

Comment: Hi hope all is well, do you mind having a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121600/app-stops-working-when-i-keep-sending-multiple-messages-with-socket-io